# DRF, update a single field in nested serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

these are my models:

```
class ADS(models.Model):

    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, related_name="ads")
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description_2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    display_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    final_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    mobile_url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "ads"
```

and:

```
class AdsImages(models.Model):

    ads = models.ForeignKey(ADS,blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',default='media/None/no-img.jpg')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "ads_images"
```

I have a nested serializer, as you can see the second model is a table with images, so I am uploading asynchronously the images via AngularJs. As you can see the `ForeignKey(ADS, blank=True, null=True)`, so I am not filling it for the first time. My question is that how to update after that the ads field.

here are my serializers:

```
class AdsImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True,allow_empty_file=True)

   class Meta:
       model = AdsImages
       fields = ('id','image','ads',)

class ADSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    adsImages = AdsImagesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ADS
        fields = ('headline','description_1','description_2','display_url','final_url','mobile_url','advertiser','adsImages',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial updates
By default, serializers must be passed values for all required fields or they will raise validation errors. You can use the partial argument in order to allow partial updates

```
# Update `comment` with partial data
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, data={'content': u'foo bar'}, partial=True)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more the answer, i need foreach image uploaded before, to update the foreignKey of the ads. Because first I upload the images, than create the ads.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. This works for non nested fields only.